# Bootstrap lightbox error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use bootstrap lightbox I use lightbox from here http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/   But I get an error

> "bootstrap-lightbox.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'Constructor' of undefined"

How can I solve this problem?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/lightbox/bootstrap-lightbox.min.css" type="text/css">    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/lightbox/bootstrap-lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <a id='myLightbox' class='lightbox hide fade'  tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-hidden='true'>
         <a class='lightbox-content'>
            <img src='$resim' class='img-responsive' style='min-width:230px; height:190px;' >
            <div class='lightbox-caption'></div>
            <a href='$page_url' target='_blank'><img style='width:100%; height:50px;' src='$img_url'></a>
        </a>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including the following elements:

- Bootstrap CSS
- Bootstrap Lightbox CSS
- jQuery
- Bootstrap Lightbox JavaScript

But you're not including the Bootstrap Javascript (which should be done before the Bootstrap Lightbox one).

For example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If you need more informations, [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) can help you.

A working example is the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/lightbox/bootstrap-lightbox.min.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#demoLightbox">
      <img src='so-icon.png' class='img-responsive' style='min-width:230px; height:190px;' >
    </a>

    <div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class='lightbox-dialog'>
            <div class='lightbox-content'>
                <img src="so-icon.png">
                <div class='lightbox-caption'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://adresinden.com/mobile/asset/lightbox/bootstrap-lightbox.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Please note, this project is no longer maintained and does not works out of the box with Bootstrap 3.3.6. I'm using Bootstrap 2 in the example.**

The other possibility could be that one of `$resim`, `$page_url` or `$img_url` is not defined in your page.

Comment: I added all bootstrap components I updated my question but I get same error

Comment: I added a full working example and another possibility for the error.

Comment: When I use lightbox.min.js I get error I think there is a different problem.

Comment: Since the example I posted is working out of the box, you should verify my last suggestion to check if everything is defined. If yes, do you have any other code in the page that could raise the error? Does the example works for you? What are the differences between the example and your actual code?

Comment: I tried your suggestion on local When I click image doesnt working

Comment: Ok, updated the example again for you to not get your error in the initial question, have the lightbox to open but please note that this library does not works out of the box with the version of Bootstrap you're using.